# Identify if a function is a nested function

Tags: python, function, reflection, closures

How can I identify whether or not a given function is:

1. A closure function
2. A nested function which isn't a closure
3. Not a nested function

I know I can say `len(function.__closure__) > 0` but this would only answer whether or not this is a closure. What about a non-closure nested function? And is there a better way to do this?

Comment: All nested functions are closures, whether or not there is anything to actually close over.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? If the function doesn't close over any variables, the fact that it's nested makes no difference.

Comment: What do you need this for, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm poking around with code injection into existing functions at runtime, and have realized I need to treat closures differently while doing so.

Comment: @AvivCohn: only if there are closed-over names. If you are patching such functions, see [Can you patch \*just\* a nested function with closure, or must the whole outer function be repeated?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27550228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* difference between a nested function with an empty closed-over set of names, and a function defined at the module level, is their `__qualname__`. All functions have a `__closure__` attribute, which is empty when there is no closed-over set of names.

The `__qualname__` attribute is writeable, so is not a *reliable* way of detecting a nested function, but you could look for the string `.<locals>.` in it:

```
>>> def foo():
...     def bar():
...         pass
...     return bar
...
>>> foo().__qualname__
'foo.<locals>.bar'
```

Nested functions that do use closed-over names, will have a non-empty `__closure__` tuple.